using the bluebird's map function
I'm not sure I'm using the Bluebird.map operator correctly.
Basically the function looks like so:
    async import(
        credentialImportData: CredentialImportData[],
    ): Promise<ImportCredentialResponse> {
        const credentials = await bluebird.Promise.map(
            credentialImportData,
            (record) => {
                const userId = record.userId;
                const credential = this.credentialService.findByUserId(userId);
                if (!!credential) {
                    this.credentialService.deleteAllForUser(userId);
                }
                return this.credentialService.create(
                    record.providerName,
                    record.userId,
                    record.merchantName,
                    record.paymentMethod,
                    record.data,
                );
            },
            {
                concurrency: 16,
            },
        ).map((record) => this.credentialService.mapToResponse(record));
        return { credentials };
    }

I'd say I have two points of confusion. The first one: the credential in the first map is a Promise and one would assume that they have to await it. But then I would have to make the mapper arg in the map function async. If I do this then would it still be concurrent?
